# Updating One List with values from another list based on a condition

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two lists lets say:

```
List1 = [{"name":"john", "limit":"21"},{"name":"edith", "limit":"21"}, {"name":"sam", "limit":"50"}]

List2 = [{"name":"john", "limit":"21"},{"name":"john", "limit":"21"} {"name":"edith", "limit":"21"}, {"name":"sam", "limit":"30"}, {"name":"sam", "limit":"30"}]
```

What is the best way to update elements in `List2` with values from elements in `List1` based on the condition that the value of name in `List1` is equal to value of name in `List2`

I'm hoping I can find a solution using LINQ, like one below used to select elements

```
var list = List2.FindAll(y => List1.Any(x => y.name==x.name));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your condition is a simple "equals" condition, you can use a join

```
from source in list1
join target in list2 on source.name equals target.name
select new {target.name, source.limit}
```

Here's a simple test based on the data from the question:

```cs
var list1 = new List<dynamic>{new {name = "john", limit = "21"}, new {name = "edith", limit = "21"}, new {name = "sam", limit = "50"}};
var list2 = new List<dynamic>{new {name = "john", limit = "21"}, new {name = "john", limit = "21"}, new {name = "edith", limit = "21"}, new {name = "sam", limit = "30"}, new {name = "sam", limit = "30"}};

var query = from source in list1
    join target in list2 on source.name equals target.name
    select new {target.name, source.limit};

foreach (var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"name = {x.name}, limit = {x.limit}");
}
```

Outputs:

```
name = john, limit = 21
name = john, limit = 21
name = edith, limit = 21
name = sam, limit = 50
name = sam, limit = 50
```